# Android progress dialog shows but never dismisses and app stays on progress dialog

Tags: php, android

I am using Volley to send a login request to login.php that is on my server. When I click login, it should either give errors or log you in. I am having the issue where it shows the progress dialog and does nothing else and the progress dialog never goes away. Anyone know what might be the issue?

```
package com.application.application;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MemberLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String URL = "http://www.example.com/login.php";
    private StringRequest request;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_member_login);

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

        email.requestFocus();

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MemberLogin.this, MemberAccess.class));
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.show();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                                User user = new User(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                                Toast.makeText(MemberLogin.this, jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
                                userLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
                                startActivity(new Intent(MemberLogin.this, MemberHome.class));
                            } else {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(MemberLogin.this, jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                password.setText("");
                                if (email.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    email.requestFocus();
                                } else {
                                    password.requestFocus();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        return hashMap;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to be calling progressDialog.dismiss() in the success case as well or not?

Comment: @caszi on success, when it changes to a different activity, it normally closes the progress dialog as well. But, I am leaving the fields empty and hitting login so it should be giving me an error. I have this working on another app I made but that one is a little different since I am using only fragments. I am not using fragments here and it isn't working. And I did make necessary changes to the code since I am not using fragments.

Comment: Is the failure Toast message appearing? Does that code get executed?

Comment: @caszi no, toast does not get executed

Answer (score 0):

You need to update this method like this :

```
  login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
 {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response)
      {
           progressDialog.show();
           try {
                 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                 if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 User user = new User(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                 Toast.makeText(MemberLogin.this, jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
                 userLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
                 startActivity(new Intent(MemberLogin.this, MemberHome.class));

                 } else {
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 Toast.makeText(MemberLogin.this, jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                            hashMap.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            return hashMap;
                        }
                    };
                    requestQueue.add(request);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the place where you are dismissing your dialog from is not reachable.

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
```

Check of all other scenarios and places where you need to dismiss all your dialogs.

One suggestion is set dialog Cancelable as true i.e. progressDialog.setCancelable(false); At least, user will have choice to cancel and close the app.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your answer as below:

```
  login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                            User user = new User(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(MemberLogin.this, jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(true);
                            userLocalStore.storeUserData(user);
                            startActivity(new Intent(MemberLogin.this, MemberHome.class));
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(MemberLogin.this, jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            password.setText("");
                            if (email.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                email.requestFocus();
                            } else {
                                password.requestFocus();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
              public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)    {    progressDialog.dismiss(); }}){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password", password.getText().toString());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    return hashMap;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}
```

}